# android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-context

I have this taskDataBase

```
@Database(
        entities = [
            Todo::class
        ],
        version = 1
)
abstract class TaskDataBase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract val taskDao: TaskDao

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: TaskDataBase? = null

        fun getInstance(context: Context): TaskDataBase {
            synchronized(this){
                return INSTANCE ?: Room.databaseBuilder(
                        context.applicationContext,
                        TaskDataBase::class.java,
                        "task_db"
                ).build().also {
                    INSTANCE = it
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the mainActivity is like this

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), TodoAdapter.OnItemLongClickListener {
    private var todoList = mutableListOf(
            Todo("First Todo item", false),
            Todo("Second Todo item", true),
            Todo("Third Todo item", false),
            Todo("Forth Todo item", true),
            Todo("Fifth Todo item", false),
            Todo("Sixth Todo item", true),
            Todo("Seventh Todo item", false)
    )
    private val adapter = TodoAdapter(todoList, this)
    private val dao:TaskDao = TaskDataBase.getInstance(this).taskDao
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        rvTodos.adapter = adapter
        rvTodos.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
```

when i run the app i get this error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
```

it is telling me there is an error in the context.
I don't know what to do. I tried to change but it didn't work out that much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the context to the attribute before the context exists.

You can assign the context after `onCreate` finishes.

You can declare these attributes. Then you can set the values ​​after the `setContentView`.

```
private var dao:TaskDao;

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        dao = TaskDataBase.getInstance(this).taskDao
}
```